# Routes in laravel5 don't work correctly

Tags: php, laravel, caching, routes

Today I have the following problem with this routes , It has never happened to me before now.

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'subastas/creado', 'class' => 'form')) !!}

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('Your Name') !!}
    {!! Form::text('name', null, 
        array('required', 
              'class'=>'form-control', 
              'placeholder'=>'Your name')) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('Your E-mail Address') !!}
    {!! Form::text('email', null, 
        array('required', 
              'class'=>'form-control', 
              'placeholder'=>'Your e-mail address')) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('Your Message') !!}
    {!! Form::textarea('message', null, 
        array('required', 
              'class'=>'form-control', 
              'placeholder'=>'Your message')) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Contact Us!', 
      array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) !!}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

In my route controller

```
Route::post('subastas/creado', array(
    'as' => 'subastas/creado',
    'uses' => 'SubastaController@creado'
    ));
```

My controller

```
public function creado()
    {
        $usuario = new Subasta();
        $usuario->name= \Request::input('name');    
        $usuario->save();

    }
```

When I send the form I recieve this url ? Any idea about this problem ?

```
http://localhost/laravel30/public/subastas/create?_token=X93VGoFhFL9YaPYZfrTlyvn0ph9KE6Om00KmMaiv&name=asdafs&email=kfh1992%40gmail.com&message=
```

Comment: Add form method "post"

Comment: post your whole routes file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have another route of `subastas/creado` for the `GET` request to display the form.

In your `Form::open()` you're using that to generate the URL, laravel is seeing that as a `GET` route as thats the first one registered in your `routes.php` and changing the form method to `GET` rather than the expected `POST`

The solution is to change the name of the route and use that in your `Form::open()`

```
Route::post('subastas/creado', [
    'as' => 'subastas/creado/post',
    'uses' => 'SubastaController@creado',
]);
```

Then you can use the following to generate the correct form opening tag.

```
Form::open(['route' => 'subastas/creado/post'])
```

Comment: I have a problem with another view , I don't close the forms.and I don't work correctly , but the code I put before is the same.